# Categorization the list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, categorization

help me please I'm trying to find out the fastest and logical way to categorize tuple list by values of the first tuple element.
for example I have a list with tuples like

```py
a = [(378, 123), (100, 12), (112, 23), (145, 14), (165, 34), (178, 45), (227, 32), (234, 12), (356, 15)] # and more and more
```

How I can dynamically categorize it into a groups like

```py
100to150 = [(100, 12), (112, 23), (145, 14)]
150to200 = [(165, 34), (178, 45)]
200to250 = [(227, 32), (234, 12)]
350to400 = [(378, 123), (356, 15)]
```

In this way I used step 50, but I want to have an ability to change it of course. It doesn't matter what will be in output, maybe list in list for example 
`[[(100, 112), (124, 145)], [(165, 12), (178, 12)], [(234, 14)], [(356, 65)]]` (random data) or maybe a list with a tuple, it doesn't matter. I just want to have an ability to get the length of the category and print category out. Thank you much.

Comment: Show what you tried first

Comment: @RMPR `steps = list(range(0, max(l) + step, step)) 
new = [[number for number in l if prev <= number < next_] for prev, next_ in zip(steps, steps[1:])]`
But it is okay only for list of the values...

Comment: @Derad: please put your example code in your question, to enhance its quality, and letting the others benefit from your question, and evtl. from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. This will give of course give you back a categorized dictionary though, not separate variables.

```
a = [(378, 123), (100, 12), (112, 23), (145, 14), (165, 34), (178, 45), (227, 32), (234, 12), (356, 15)] # and more and more

def categorize(array, step=50):
        d = dict()
        for e in array:
                from_n = e[0]//step*step
                s = f'{from_n}to{from_n+step}'
                if s not in d:
                        d[s] = []
                d[s].append(e)
        return d

print(categorize(a))
```

Output:

```
{'350to400': [(378, 123), (356, 15)], '100to150': [(100, 12), (112, 23), (145, 14)], '150to200': [(165, 34), (178, 45)], '200to250': [(227, 32), (234, 12)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [x for x in a if 100<x[0]<150]
```

I should say this is the minimal you should need to get going.  If you want the full solution, you could imagine putting this into some type of function where your low and high (100, 150 in this example) are arguments.  You could even have a list of highs/lows and then loop through them all and collect all the out put as a list of lists of tuples.

Answer (score -1):

You can see something like this:
Using a dictionary to store grouped values, to instantly get them later.

```
def categorize_by_first(pairs, step=50):
    d = {}
    for pair in pairs:
        range_start = (pair[0] // step) * step
        dict_key_name = f"{range_start}_{range_start + step}"

        if not d.get(dict_key_name):
            d[dict_key_name] = []

        d[dict_key_name].append(pair)

    return d
```

Output:

```
{'350_400': [(378, 123), (356, 15)],
 '100_150': [(100, 12), (112, 23), (145, 14)],
 '150_200': [(165, 34), (178, 45)],
 '200_250': [(227, 32), (234, 12)]}
```

Time complexity of grouping is O(n) (we only once iterate over the input list).

Time complexity of [getting element from a dictionary](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(1)

So that should be efficient.

Comment: I just realized that [Grigor Bezirganyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5677092/grigor-bezirganyan) answered with the same approach before I did.